# loop an include with a variable

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, while-loop, do-while

I have a query I need to loop for as many instances of Proveedir_ID unique values possible.

My query is:

```
 <?php
require('Connection.php');


  $consulta="SELECT Proveedor_Logo, Giro2_ID, Producto_Nombre,     Producto_Descripcion, Producto_Precio, Producto_Imagen, Producto_Prioridad FROM     Natan_Procesos WHERE Proveedor_ID = 1";

?>
<!-- EMPIEZA EL CODIGO BUENO -->
<div align="center">
    <div align="center" style="width: -600; -moz-box-align: center;     alignment-adjust: central; alignment-baseline: central; vertical-align: central; z-index: auto;">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p> Opciones de <? echo $rows['giro2']; ?></p>
        <?php

        $rows = array();
        try {
            $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT Proveedor_Logo, Giro2_ID,     Producto_Nombre, Producto_Descripcion, Producto_Precio, Producto_Imagen, Producto_Prioridad FROM Natan_Procesos WHERE Producto_Prioridad = 1 AND Categoria_ID=2");
            $sth->execute(array(
            /*    $ead,*/
             /*   $eac*/
            ));
            while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
                $Proveedor_Logo = $row['Proveedor_Logo'];
                $Giro2_ID = $row['Giro2_ID'];
                $Producto_Nombre = $row['Producto_Nombre'];
                $Producto_Descripcion = $row['Producto_Descripcion'];
                $Producto_Precio = $row['Producto_Precio'];
                $Producto_Imagen = $row['Producto_Imagen'];
                $Producto_Prioridad = $row['Producto_Prioridad'];
                $rows[] = $row;
               }
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Database operation failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
        ?>
    </div></div>
<div align="center">
    <div align="center"
         style="width: -600; -moz-box-align: center; alignment-adjust: central; alignment-baseline: central; vertical-align: central; z-index: auto;">
        <table width="800" border="0">
            <?php
            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                ?>
               <tr>
                <td><input name="platofuerte" type="radio" value="" />
                </td>
                <td><img src='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['Producto_Imagen']); ?>' alt='image' />
                </td>
                <td width=""><input name="" type="label" value='<?php echo $row['Producto_Nombre']; ?>' />
                </td>
                <td width=""><input name="" type="label" value='<?php echo $row['Producto_Descripcion']; ?>' />
                </td>
                <td width=""><input name="" type="label" value='$<?php echo $row['Producto_Precio']; ?>' />
                </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            } ?>
        </table>
    </div></div>   

<!--BUSQUEDA DE PLATO FUERTE -->

<div align="center">
    <div align="center" style="width: -600; -moz-box-align: center; alignment-adjust: central; alignment-baseline: central; vertical-align: central; z-index: auto;">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p> Opciones de <? echo $rows['giro2']; ?></p>
        <?php
        $rows = array();
        try {
            $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT Proveedor_Logo, Giro2_ID, Producto_Nombre, Producto_Descripcion, Producto_Precio, Producto_Imagen, Producto_Prioridad FROM Natan_Procesos WHERE Producto_Prioridad = 2");
            $sth->execute(array(
            /*    $ead,*/
             /*   $eac*/
            ));
            while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
                $Proveedor_Logo = $row['Proveedor_Logo'];
                $Giro2_ID = $row['Giro2_ID'];
                $Producto_Nombre = $row['Producto_Nombre'];
                $Producto_Descripcion = $row['Producto_Descripcion'];
                $Producto_Precio = $row['Producto_Precio'];
                $Producto_Imagen = $row['Producto_Imagen'];
                $Producto_Prioridad = $row['Producto_Prioridad'];
                $rows[] = $row;
            }
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Database operation failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
        ?>
    </div></div>
<div align="center">
    <div align="center"
         style="width: -600; -moz-box-align: center; alignment-adjust: central; alignment-baseline: central; vertical-align: central; z-index: auto;">
        <table width="800" border="0">
            <?php
            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                ?>
               <tr><td><input name="platofuerte" type="radio" value="" />
                </td>
                   <td><img src='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['Producto_Imagen']); ?>' alt='image' />
                </td>
                   <td width=""><input name="" type="label" value='<?php echo $row['Producto_Nombre']; ?>' />
                </td>
                   <td width=""><input name="" type="label" value='<?php echo $row['Producto_Descripcion']; ?>' />
                </td>
                   <td width=""><input name="" type="label" value='$<?php echo $row['Producto_Precio']; ?>' />
                </td></tr>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </table>
    </div></div>

<!-- BUSQUEDA  POSTRE -->

<div align="center">
    <div align="center" style="width: -600; -moz-box-align: center; alignment-adjust: central; alignment-baseline: central; vertical-align: central; z-index: auto;">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p> Opciones de <? echo $rows['giro2']; ?></p>
        <?php

        $rows = array();
        try {
            $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT Proveedor_Logo, Giro2_ID, Producto_Nombre, Producto_Descripcion, Producto_Precio, Producto_Imagen, Producto_Prioridad FROM Natan_Procesos WHERE Producto_Prioridad = 3");
            $sth->execute(array(
            /*    $ead,*/
             /*   $eac*/
            ));
            while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
                $Proveedor_Logo = $row['Proveedor_Logo'];
                $Giro2_ID = $row['Giro2_ID'];
                $Producto_Nombre = $row['Producto_Nombre'];
                $Producto_Descripcion = $row['Producto_Descripcion'];
                $Producto_Precio = $row['Producto_Precio'];
                $Producto_Imagen = $row['Producto_Imagen'];
                $Producto_Prioridad = $row['Producto_Prioridad'];
                $rows[] = $row;



            }
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Database operation failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div align="center">
    <div align="center"
         style="width: -600; -moz-box-align: center; alignment-adjust: central; alignment-baseline: central; vertical-align: central; z-index: auto;">
        <table width="800" border="0">
            <?php
            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                ?>
               <tr>

                <td><input name="platofuerte" type="radio" value="" />
                </td>
                 <td><img src='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['Producto_Imagen']); ?>' alt='image' />
                </td>
                <td width=""><input name="" type="label" value='<?php echo $row['Producto_Nombre']; ?>' />
                </td>
                <td width=""><input name="" type="label" value='<?php echo $row['Producto_Descripcion']; ?>' />
                </td>
                <td width=""><input name="" type="label" value='$<?php echo $row['Producto_Precio']; ?>' />
                </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>   
<!-- TERMINA EL CÓDIGO CHIDO -->


   -------------------------------------------------------<br><br>   
      <input type="submit" name="Reservar" id="Reservar" value="Reservar" />
    </p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
</form>
```

So I can show the results for Proveedor_ID =1, but now I need to have it also check for every other unique Proveedor_ID value after that that includes the same Giro2_ID. I am looking for the code to wrap all of this code into a while loop in PDO preferably.

I need the while to be unlimited to all the possible instances of unique values of Proveedor_ID possible.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `DISTINCT` and `GROUP` in your SQL statement. I cannot locate ProveedorID in your SQL statement, so i'll just provide a sample

`select * from Natan_Procesos group by ProveedorID`

`SELECT DISTINCT ON ProveedorID * FROM  Natan_Procesos WHERE Producto_Prioridad = 1;`

Comment: yup, my sql will work as well. try the second statement.

Comment: so my filters from each Proveedor_ID are the value of Giro2_ID has to be the same throughout all Proveedor_ID values and Producto_Prioridad with values from 1 through 4. then I repeat the same queries above for the next provider. I need to run alll queries on the same provider before moving on with the next Proveedor_ID value.

Comment: Wouldn't a normal statement will be enough in this case?

Comment: such as? a while statement or...?

Comment: tbh my brain is telling me for you to use a store the values 1-4 foreach loop and run it with the query, yet another side cannot process what you are saying

Comment: ok. I have several providers that offer 4 types of products each.  I can output 1 provider only so far with a full list of its products.  I am thinking of using a while loop to run the same cycle with each other provider I have(Proveedor_ID) that is where I need the help. I havent used DISTINCT ON before so I need to research first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115930/discussion-between-natan-coats-and-ctc).